# HttpWebRequest initialization causing File Not Found exception in MonoTouch iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, httpwebrequest, filenotfoundexception, xamarin

I have two projects currently being developed in MonoTouch inside the Xamarin Studio IDE: A C# portable library project, which I am going to use as a wrapper class for making requests and handling responses to and from my server using JSON. My second project, currently, is a simple C# console-based application which I am using to test the first project as it is developed. Eventually I will remove the second project and create a new one for an iOS app which will utilize my wrapper class.

However, I'm stuck at the very beginning for some bizarre reason. I am following this tutorial on how to make HTTP web requests using the HttpWebRequest class: http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/introduction_to_web_services#2.1.1.using-httpwebrequest

I have only written the very first (well, second) line of code in the demo within my wrapper class constructor for prototyping:

```cs
using System;
using System.Net;

namespace MyWebApp
{
    public class MyWebAppClient
    {
        private string Password { get; set; }
        private string Username { get; set; }

        public MyWebAppClient (string Username, string Password)
        {
            this.Username = Username;
            this.Password = Password;
            var request = HttpWebRequest.Create (new Uri("http://google.com/"));
        }
    }
}
```

And my very simple text project:

```cs
using System;
using MyWebApp;

namespace MyTest
{
    class MainClass
    {

        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            MyWebAppClient client = new MyWebAppClient("username","password");
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the test project, I get the following exception:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' or one of its dependencies.
  at ASDFTest.MainClass.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in /Users/William/BitBucket/ASDFiOS/ASDFiOS/ASDFTest/Program.cs:11
```

If I remove that one line inside the constructor of the other project (where the HttpWebRequest object is created), the exception goes away.

Does anybody know what could be causing this? I'm completely stumped here, and I'm very new to MonoTouch.

Comment: I suspect this might be de to PCL where I *suppose* `MyWebApp` is located. Sadly there's not enough details. Can you post the full build log, state which version of Xamarin.iOS you're using, if this happens on the simulator, devices (or both) ? It might be better to file a bug report (http://bugzilla.xamarin.com) if you already have a test case you can share with us.

Answer (score 0):

Upon further investigation, it appears that the use of PCLs (where the MyWebApp namespace resides) is not fully supported (http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/28/challenges-thoughts-loves#latest). It's a bit of a shame, and I guess with some hacking it can be done, but for the sake of my project I suppose for now I will keep my solution down to a single project.